# What happened to the checkboxes in the CRM 2013 Subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Am I missing something or did Microsoft remove the capability to select a particular record in a Subgrid in CRM 2013?

[image]

In 2011 selecting a record in a subgrid would change the context of the ribbon buttons to the entity that the subgrid was displaying. Also, when a custom button was clicked on the form, we had access to primaryEntityTypeName, primaryEntity, selectedEntities in the event handler.

This was a really useful feature. Does anyone know if it can be enabled somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer to [this post](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/4-things-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-Command-Bar.aspx). As you can see it 3-rd point from now there is no ribbon bar for subgrid as it was before, there are only 2 buttons on top of it: Add New and Open Associated Sub Grid. There is no way to change this.
Don't know if it will work out for yours situation but you may use Associated Views like in [this post](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2013/10/29/context-sensitive-sub-grid-commands-in-crm-2013.aspx).